# How to pass the -k or --insecure argument to curl in the R package "httr"?

Tags: r, curl, httr

**TLDR:** I'm getting an error message saying:

> schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676185/the-certificate-chain-issued-by-an-untrusted-authority), I've got to force curl into ignoring certificate errors, thus requiring the argument `-k` or `-insecure`.
A quick Google search led me to `set_config(config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ))`, that did absolutely nothing...

Does anybody know the correct httr syntax to properly command curl to ignoring that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** I got the issue fixed with this command:

```
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L, ssl_verifyhost = 0L))
```